# Why pay for Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

If I do not need more Google Drive space than the free version offers (currently 15 GB) what are the exact benefits I receive with the pay version?

Answer (score 5):

Google only [charges for more storage](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375123?hl=en) on Google Drive (which can be used across Drive, GMail and Google+ Photos), there isn't an improved service you can pay for. Even in the [business plans](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/products.html#drive) you are only paying for extra space.

So if you don't need more space, there is no need to pay.